# Handling only pressed items in an Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image: Figure 1][image]

The image above shows the type of styling i would like to apply to only items that gets pressed in array.

The code below is what i have done so far. All the items in the array keeps getting the styles applied to them whenever anyone of their siblings gets pressed. So my question here is, how do i focus my events(applying styles) to the only pressed sibling? This code is for the second gif

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text ,StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, } from 'react-native';
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import {itemSelect} from "../../Store/Actions/index"

 class Selections extends Component {

    state={
        highlighted: false,
        id: null
    }
// The purpose of this function is to set the state to the target index on press
indexStateHandler = (i) =>{

         this.setState({
             id: i
         })

}


    //The purpose of this function is to set styles for the targeted index
    highlightStateHandler = () =>{     

            if(this.state.highlighted == true){ 
                this.setState({
                    highlighted:false
                })

            }
            else{
                this.setState({
                    highlighted:true
                })

            }

           }

    highlightHandler = (i,options) =>{
        this.indexStateHandler(i)
        this.highlightStateHandler()
        console.log("index: "+i)
        console.log(this.state.highlighted)


       // this.props.priceEdit(options)
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log(this.state.highlighted)
    };



  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.selectionWrapper}>
        <View style={styles.label}><Text style={{color: "black"}}>{this.props.label}</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
        {this.props.options.map((options, i) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.highlightHandler(options.uid, options)} key={i}>
            <View style={this.state.id == options.uid ?styles.highlighted:styles.options} > <Text style={styles.text}>{options.name}</Text> </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
              )
        )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    selectionWrapper:{
        width: '100%',
        height: 100,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'red',
    },
    label:{
        flex: 1,

    }
    ,
    listContainer:{
        flex: 3,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        alignItems: 'center',
        // backgroundColor: "#7fffd4"
    },
    options:{
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#d0b783",
        // backgroundColor: ""

    },
    text:{
        color: 'black',
        textAlign: 'center'
    },

    highlighted:{
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        // borderColor: "#d0b783",
        backgroundColor: "#d0b783"

    }
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
        select: (bool)=>dispatch(itemSelect(bool))
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return{
        id: state.cart.id
    }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Selections)
```

## UPDATED

I used the index of the elements for targeting. Below is the code for it.
According to the gif you will see that everything works just fine except that, when i press an element for the second time(which is vanilla according to the current example), it didn't turn the styles back on because of the logic. I know it is behaving this way because the 'booln' in the state evaluates to false when the current index and the previous index are the same as you will see in the code. Have a look at the code and see where it needs improvement please.

```
...
state={

    index: null,
    booln:false
}

highlightHandler = (optionIndex) => {

    this.setState(prevState =>({

        index: optionIndex,
        booln:prevState.index == optionIndex? false: true
    }))
}

 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.selectionWrapper}>
        <View style={styles.label}><Text style={{color: "black"}}>{this.props.label}</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
        {this.props.options.map((options, i) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.highlightHandler(options.uid, options)} key={i}>
            <View style={this.state.booln&& this.state.index == options.uid? styles.highlighted:styles.options} > <Text style={styles.text}>{options.name}</Text> </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
              )
        )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LATEST PROBLEM**

So according to the second gif i posted yesterday, i was having problems with toggling the styles on an item after the logic implemented evaluates to true; which was to remove the styles when the previous index and the current index evaluates to true as seen in the updated code above. The predicament that code got me into was that, once the previous and current state of the index becomes equal, there was no way for me to invoke any other change since the index is always going to be in state if i continue pressing that same item.

**LATEST SOLUTION**

What i now did was, to track the number of times an item gets pressed, by creating a counter variable(tracker) in the function and also a tracker variable in the state(with the purpose of retaining the value of the tracker). I also had to find a way to reset the counter to 0 whenever i press another item(sibling), and the only way to achieve that was to check if the previous index(this.state.index) is not equal to the current index(optionIndex).

After that, what was left for me to do was to figure out how to keep toggling the styles on a continual press of an item(sibling). Then, i mapped the behavior of a toggle by setting a condition in my render function to evaluate to true after the item gets pressed after certain number of times(purpose of the tracker) as seen in the code below and with that i got my toggles to work on each item. Sorry for the verbosity of the answer :)

```
state={
    tracker:0,
    index: null,
    booln:false,

}

highlightHandler = (optionIndex,options) => {
    //Assigned (this.state.tracker) to the tracker variable in order of retaining value after each invocation

    let tracker=this.state.tracker
    this.state.index!==optionIndex?tracker=0:tracker++

    this.setState(prevState =>({
        tracker:tracker,
        index: optionIndex,
        booln:prevState.index == optionIndex? false: true,

    }))
}


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.selectionWrapper}>
        <View style={styles.label}><Text style={{color: "black"}}>{this.props.label}</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
        {this.props.options.map((options, i) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.highlightHandler(options.uid, options)} key={i}>
            <View style={(this.state.booln&& this.state.index == options.uid) ||
                 (this.state.tracker!=0 && this.state.tracker%2==0) &&this.state.index== options.uid 
                 ? styles.highlighted:styles.options} > <Text style={styles.text}>{options.name}</Text> </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
              )
        )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Shout out to all the contributors of this question, for providing me the responses that forced my perspective on how to approach the problem from a different angle. Let me know what you all think. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing your `state.highlighted` to either `true` or `false` why not store the `index` or `id` of the `data` pressed and then in your ternary operator, you check if the `id` is equal to the `id` stored in `state.highlighted`. Furthermore, you want to track multiple pressed items, you can store their `ids` or `index` in an array and check if their `id` or `index` is in that array to apply the styling

Comment: ok, so are you implying that i store the id of the pressed items inside the state.highlighted instead of a boolean value?

Comment: Exactly. Or if you want to track more than one pressed item, their id's can be stored in an array

Comment: Nice! it worked but, i am unable to remove the styling on the item when i press the item for the second time. Let me update the code for you to see.

Comment: That has to do with your logic. You can check if the id was in `state` before either storing or removing it from `state`

Comment: The id is always going to be in state as long as i keep pressing that same item. The only condition that will remove the styling from an item is if i press another item in the array which is going to set the state to that clicked items id.

Comment: That was why i used that boolean value to help me keep track of that. But what do you suggest i do from here?

Comment: To get you right, you want to remove the `id` on second press which will in turn remove the `styling` I'll suggest you check if the `id` of the item being pressed is already in state, you then set the value in state to null.

Comment: yes, and that is the logic i applied to remove the the styling on second press. Check my updated code please. The new challenge i am facing now is, to turn the styling back on after i press the same element for the third time.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep an array with the status (pressed/unpressed => true/false) of each single elements in your array. By default they are all unpressed (false).
I would then toggle the press status at the onClick handler and render accordingly:

```
...
state = {
    pressed: this.props.options.map(_ => false)
}

onPress = optionIndex => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        pressed: prevState.pressed.map((option, index) => {
            return optionIndex === index ? !option : option
        })
    }))
}

optionStyle = optionIndex =>
    this.state.pressed[optionIndex]
    ? styles.highlighted
    : styles.options

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.selectionWrapper}>
            <View style={styles.label}>
                <Text style={{color: "black"}}>
                    {this.props.label}
                </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                {
                    this.props.options.map((options, index) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => this.onPress(index)}
                            key={i}
                        >
                            <View style={ this.optionStyle(index) }>
                                <Text style={styles.text}>{options.name}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    ))
                }
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: haha i am sorry but this is my first time seeing this type of state initialization. What just happened there?? A bit of a noob in the space sir!

Comment: I think the optionStyle function is incomplete because i kept getting an error there when i ran your code is incomplete.

Comment: What is happening is:

– the state get set with a `pressed` array. The initial value of the array is a series of `false` value, one for each option in your `props.options` prop;
– the `onPress` simply toggle the boolean that represents the press state of each option. The result is achieved mapping a new array of statuses from the previous state;
– the `optionStyle` method just return the proper style looking into the state whether the given optionIndex is pressed or not;

Is it clear?

Comment: yes i understand your logic now! Just applied it and i encountered two unwanted behaviors.1) It's a multiple selection logic whereby the styling of the previously pressed item doesn't get removed when another sibling gets pressed.2) The last sibling in the array seemed to be excluded from the event(no style gets applied to it when pressed).

Comment: I found a way to remove styling of the previous sibling when another is pressed by using the index as an extra condition to the optionstyle function. What i can't seem to figure out how to do though, is to change the boolean of the previous sibling to false when i press another one, so that it passes the condition the next time i press it and have styles applied to it.
PS:I will edit your code to show where i made the changes.

Comment: @mujeexminiminer maybe I just badly understood the problem (I'm not an english nativespeaker). You would like to get behaviour like radio buttons? If so, I'll post a slightly different answer.

Comment: haha, neither am i. I actually learned a lot from your code because it inspired and guided me to think of another way of approaching the problem. I have made significant progress from where i started but still missing one last function which is now to remove the styles from the element(sibling) when pressed. Let me try and see if i can add another gif for you to check it out.

Comment: haha i already posted it yesterday! Anyways i finally found a solution to the problem. I will provide the answer soon. I hope to hear what you will think about it.